# Upload iOS app to my individual Apple Developer Account

Tags: ios

I have invited my developer in iTunes Connect to my account with the roles developer, marketing and app manager. I have an existing Apple Developer account as an individual. My developer is now complaining that he cannot publish the new app as he need some access to the Apple Developer account.

Am I missing something. Because I couldn't find any option to add him in my Apple Developer Account, only in iTunes Connect where he has access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an app to submit on AppStore, we need a couple of things like:

1. Apple Distribution Certificate
2. Register a bundle identifier
3. Distribution Provisioning Profile for your app.

All the mentioned things can be completed on https://developer.apple.com

As you have an individual account, so you can do 3 things...

1. Create the mentioned things and send them to your developer
2. Give your developer access to your developer creds and your developer can do it for you.
3. Convert your individual account to the Company account if possible and give your developer proper rights to do the required things.

Please comment if you have any questions.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your developer would need an iOS development certificate to build the app under your account, and your iOS distribution certificate to distribute it (e.g., upload to your iTunesConnect, now AppstoreConnect, account). This is before any question of access permissions for AppstoreConnect.

So you would need either:

- company developer.apple.com account where you can assign your developer the developer role
- share your Apple ID credentials with your developer, which I guess you don't want to do